# SceneKit Optimization

Tags: ios, scenekit

I want to display the same `SCNGeometry` 1000 times, but with a specific animation (eg SCNActions for rotation, movement,...) and a different image as diffuse material.

After checking documentation and nice WWDC presentations, the best method I found to create one node is (so it is called 1000 times)

```
//self is a SCNNode
//helper.getStar3D() is a SCNNode template which has been flattened
//the geometry is light (36 triangles according to scenekit statistic)

//need to copy the geometry and material so it is not shared by all nodes 
self.geometry=helper.getStar3D().geometry.copy() as SCNGeometry
self.geometry.firstMaterial = helper.getStar3D().geometry.firstMaterial.copy() as SCNMaterial

// texture has been extracted from a SKTextureAtlas 
self.geometry.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents=allTextures.firstObject as SKTexture
```

However on an iPad Air I'm only reaching 40fps (and 27 fps when animating the texture via SCNAction with a block that update firstMaterial.diffuse.contents )

I thought that using a SKTextureAtlas (so all the images are on the same texture) and use the same geometry (apparently when  you copy a geometry, data are shared - cf [Building a Game with sceneKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/)), I would get more fps because it should allow OpenGL optimization. I tried to play with a lot of parameters of SceneKit but with no success.

For the notice: the SceneKit statistics tells that there are 1000 draw calls, and Graphics stats in Xcode are :cpu 18ms, GPU is 22ms, tiler 18%, renderer 80%, device 88% (can't wait for the new SceneKit statistics module in Xcode!)

So my question is : Do you think it's normal performance or is there a way to optimize what I want to do in SceneKit? Thanks!

**EDIT**: Actually SKTextureAtlas does not seems to optimize the rendering but seems to reduce the frame rate. if I use UIImage instead of SKTexture coming from a SKTextureAtlas, I've got 25% improvement (50fps). Animating the texture (updating the texture of each object each 0.2 seconds) is really killing performance (20fps) using SKTextureAtlas or UIImages. I think I'm missing something here because SKTextureAtlas are usually used for optimization.

Comment: 1000 draw calls is quite a lot, which is probably why you spend 18ms on the CPU. The high render utilization could be because of an excessive number if texture sampling, but it's hard to tell with this little information.

Comment: Are there also 1000 different textures? What size are the textures? Are there mipmaps? Does all geometry objects animate individually?

Comment: I'm really not an OpenGL expert but I thought that if one uses the same geometry and the same texture (it is an atlas with several textures...), it would help to reduce the numbers of draw calls - but perhaps SceneKit is not doing this kind of optimization ?

Comment: So there are several textures but in one graphic file (atlas...) - it is about 70 256*256 images.

Comment: As long as each object is being transformed individually, you pretty much have to make one draw call per object. (That's not entirely true. But it can be helpful to think of it like that)

Comment: Have you tried using flattenedClone? I know you are indicating that the issue is texture related, but SceneKit also has major performance issues with a large number of geometries, which can be greatly improved by flattening a node graph, which both reduces overall memory consumption to some degree (not sure why), and definitely speeds up rendering, presumably because it aggregates draw calls when the geometries have been flattened.

Comment: If you're really stuck for performance you can alway try lowering your content scaling factor (it can make a huge difference to performance at the cost of graphics fidelity) by setting sceneView.contentScaleFactor to a new value. I notice on my phone it's set to 3.0. You can find out the size it's actually outputting using sceneView.snapshot() and looking at the UIImages size.

Comment: Its it long shot, but the word metal comes to mind. This guy [not me] has written quite a few excellent articles on the subject here http://mattreagandev.com/?article=20161108

Comment: @DanM Hey, just wanted to say thanks. `contentScaleFactor` appears to have solved a really annoying memory problem I was having in my SceneKit project. Really awesome stuff, thank you!